# Why does float('3') apparently return a TypeError in Python 2.6.8?

Tags: python

I have (anonymized) a hash constructed from values in Python 2.6.8:

```
sys.stderr.write('#' + str(dictionary['Field 4']) + '#\n')
kpis_found.append(float(int(dictionary['Field 1']), 1) *
    max(float(dictionary['Field 2']), 1) *
    max(float(dictionary['Field 3']), 1) *
    max(float(dictionary['Field 4']), 1) *
    max(float(dictionary['Field 5']), 1))
```

The output I get is:

```
[Fri Jul 13 09:04:44 2012] [error] [client ::1] #3#
[Fri Jul 13 09:04:44 2012] [error] [client ::1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Jul 13 09:04:44 2012] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Users/jonathan/mirror/civic/google_maps/index.cgi", line 357, in <module>
[Fri Jul 13 09:04:44 2012] [error] [client ::1]     max(float(dictionary['Field 4']), 1) *
[Fri Jul 13 09:04:44 2012] [error] [client ::1] TypeError: float() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

To the best of my knowledge, the CSV files yield (usually) strings convertible to ints, or (occasionally) strings convertible to floats. If I run into a NULL, that should be easier to diagnose. The debugging output appears to confirm that the field in question is '3'.

How is this getting a TypeError? I've run through parentheses to ensure that I'm not calculating

```
max(float(foo, bar))
```

but instead calculating

```
max(float(foo), bar)
```

Any insight would be welcome.

Comment: The confusing thing here is that Python locates the error in the last line of the multiline statement, while it actually is in the first line.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Hadn't realized that was the reason, but pretty interesting. Why isn't it the first line of a multiline statement that gets tagged?

Comment: @JAB: In CPython, each simple statement results in only a single line in the line number table of the code object, and the line number chosen is the last line of a multi-line statement.  It would be tricky to get that right in general, so the compiler does not bother.  (See also http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/93df82c18781/Objects/lnotab_notes.txt)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
float(int(dictionary['Field 1']), 1)
```

Pretty sure that's your problem. You end up with `float(<int_value>, 1)`.

This was tested with Python 3.1.2, but...

```
>>> float(1, 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    float(1, 1)
TypeError: float() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but the traceback displays a different line (suspected reason in my answer)

Comment: @OttoAllmendinger: That's what Python does for multi-line statements.  It's a bit confusing.

Comment: Upvoted and will be accepted when SO allows. Thanks; I'm wondering why the stacktrace indicated the wrong line.

Comment: @JonathanHayward -- The parser proabably condenses the entire multi-line statement into one line and tags it with the last line number.